# Is there a equation that can make the answer negative when it is odd, and positive when it is even?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

One of the exercises I got asked how it would be possible to build a set such that $B = \{−1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{−1}{3},\frac{1}{4},...\}$. Is there an equation that can make the answer negative when it is odd, and positive when it is even?

Comment: How about something like
$$
f(n) = (-1)^{n+1}
$$

Comment: Could you write it as a answer so I could do the checkmark thing? @MattiP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple, well known example of this is
$$
f(n) = (-1)^{n+1}
$$